# Custom Websocket in Redux Architecture

Tags: reactjs, websocket, redux, middleware, subscription

The more I read about this subject it seems like going down a rabbit hole. This is a new Trading application which receives realtime data through web sockets which is based on a request-response paradigm. There are three separate SPA's in which apart from initial load, every user action triggers a call to the dataStore with a new MDXQuery. So in turn I would need to make fresh subscriptions on a componentDidMount() as well as in the respective ActionCreators.I would like to streamline the code to avoid duplicate code and redundancy.

The below code helps establish a new subscription channel to streams the response through web-socket.(Unlike, most sockets.io code where it comes with a designated open,close,send)

```
    this.subscription = bus.channel(PATH, { mode: bus.wsModes.PULL }).createListener(this.onResponse.bind(this));
this.subscription.subscribe(MDXQuery);
```

If I read the REDUX documentation as to where should I place the web socket code? It mentions to create a custom middleware. 
LINK: https://redux.js.org/faq/codestructure#where-should-websockets-and-other-persistent-connections-live

But I am not very sure how could I go about using this custom web socket code framing my own middleware or doing at the component level would help to mimic this strategy.

```
const createMySocketMiddleware = (url) => {
return storeAPI => {
    let socket = createMyWebsocket(url);

    socket.on("message", (message) => {
        storeAPI.dispatch({
            type : "SOCKET_MESSAGE_RECEIVED",
            payload : message
        });
    });

    return next => action => {
        if(action.type == "SEND_WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE") {
            socket.send(action.payload);
            return;
        }

        return next(action);
    }
}
```

}

Any design inputs would really help!!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote that FAQ entry and example.

If I understand your question, you're asking about how to dynamically create additional subscriptions at runtime?

Since a Redux middleware can see every dispatched action that is passed through the middleware pipeline, you can dispatch actions that are only intended as commands for a middleware to do something.  Now, I'm not sure what an MDXQuery is, and it's also not clear what you're wanting to do with the messages received from these subscriptions.  For sake of the example, I'll assume that you want to either dispatch Redux actions whenever a subscription message is received, or potentially do some custom logic with them.

You can write a custom middleware that listens for actions like `"CREATE_SUBSCRIPTION"` and `"CLOSE_SUBSCRIPTION"`, and potentially accepts a callback function to run when a message is received.

Here's what that might look like:

```
// Add this to the store during setup
const subscriptionMiddleware = (storeAPI) => {
    let nextSubscriptionId = 0;
    const subscriptions = {};
    const bus = createBusSomehow();

    return (next) => (action) => {
        switch(action.type) {
            case "CREATE_SUBSCRIPTION" : {
                const {callback} = action;
                const subscriptionId = nextSubscriptionId;
                nextSubscriptionId++;

                const subscription = bus.channel(PATH, { mode: bus.wsModes.PULL })
                                        .createListener((...args) => {
                                            callback(dispatch, getState, ...args);
                                        });
                subscriptions[subscriptionId] = subscription;
                return subscriptionId;
            }
            case "CLOSE_SUBSCRIPTION" : {
                const {subscriptionId} = action;
                const subscription = subscriptions[subscriptionId];

                if(subscription) {
                    subscription.close();
                    delete subscriptions[subscriptionId];
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Use over in your components file
function createSubscription(callback) {
    return {type : "CREATE_SUBSCRIPTION", callback };
}

function closeSubscription(subscriptionId) {
    return {type :  "CLOSE_SUBSCRIPTION", subscriptionId};
}

// and in your component:
const actionCreators = {createSubscription, closeSubscription};

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.subscriptionId = this.props.createSubscription(this.onMessageReceived);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.closeSubscription(this.subscriptionId);
    }
}

export default connect(null, actionCreators)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Hello Mark,Firstly this is a bit of a fan moment for me, I must have read so many of your blogposts over these last two years which have benefitted me a great deal in the React-Redux applications that I have developed.

Comment: An MDX query simplified would be kind of like an sql query but a bit more complicated used for Big Data Analytics.  SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Stock_Value],[Measures].[Stock_Prices],[Measures].[Stock_Hike_Rate]} ON COLUMNS,NON EMPTY Hierarchize(DrilldownLevel([Stock].[StockId].[ALL].[AllMember])) ON ROWS FROM [StockTable] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE'

Comment: Yes the idea is to dynamically create subscriptions to the web socket in order to fetch fresh stock data.
1. when the component is getting loaded on the screen or 
2. User performs some actions on the page by choosing some new parameters from the drop down.Most screens have complex graphs created using React-vis charts or Tables.

// onResponse() is a sample promise. A promise needs to be provided for handling the subscription responses.
let subscription = bus.channel('/StockMarket', { mode: bus.wsModes.PULL }).createListener(this.onResponse.bind(this));

Comment: Hah, a fan? Nice :)  Glad my posts have been useful.  Does the example help answer your question (or at least give you an idea of how this might work in your own app), or are there aspects you're still confused about?

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your solution for my own problem which involves creating a socket instance only when a user is logged and here is how my code looks:

```js
const socketMiddleWare = url => store => {
  const socket = new SockJS(url, [], {
    sessionId: () => custom_token_id
  });
  return next => action => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case types.USER_LOGGED_IN:
        {
          socket.onopen = e => {
            console.log("Connection", e.type);

            store.dispatch({
              type: types.TOGGLE_SOCK_OPENING
            });

            if (e.type === "open") {
              store.dispatch({
                type: types.TOGGLE_SOCK_OPENED
              });
              createSession(custom_token_id, store);
              const data = {
                type: "GET_ACTIVE_SESSIONS",
                JWT_TOKEN: Cookies.get("agentClientToken")
              };
              store.dispatch({
                type: types.GET_ACTIVE_SESSIONS,
                payload: data
              });
            }
          };
          socket.onclose = () => {
            console.log("Connection closed");
            store.dispatch({
              type: types.POLL_ACTIVE_SESSIONS_STOP
            });
            // store.dispatch({ type: TOGGLE_SOCK_OPEN, payload: false });
          };
          socket.onmessage = e => {
            console.log(e)
          };
          if (
            action.type === types.SEND_SOCKET_MESSAGE
          ) {
            socket.send(JSON.stringify(action.payload));
            return;
          } else if (action.type === types.USER_LOGGED_OUT) {
            socket.close();
          }
          next(action);
        }
      default:
        next(action);
        break;
    }
  };
};
```

It doesn't work though but could you point me in the right direction. Thanks.